# Separate row to cells with different delimiters and delete unsued characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm playin around with `python` for a couple days, so I'm new all new to the game, please be gentle to me.

I'm trying to read a certain line from a `csv` file and after reading it I'm trying to `separate` and `transpose` it.

Heres what I do:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('api_plant.csv', skiprows=1, nrows=1, sep=" [,]", engine='python')

  data,"[[1614556800000, 1149], [1614643200000, 1512.1], [1614729600000, 2133.3], [1614816000000, 485.2], [1614902400000, 3091], [1614988800000, 809], [1615075200000, 1018], [1615161600000, 3232.5], [1615248000000, 1709.3], [1615334400000, 2073.5], [1615420800000, 869.2], [1615507200000, 1679.5], [1615593600000, 787.3], [1615680000000, 1509.7], [1615766400000, 1047.6], [1615852800000, 2326.5], [1615939200000, 1444.8], [1616025600000, None], [1616112000000, None], [1616198400000, None], [1616284800000, None], [1616371200000, None], [1616457600000, None], [1616544000000, None], [1616630400000, None], [1616716800000, None], [1616803200000, None], [1616889600000, None], [1616976000000, None], [1617062400000, None], [1617148800000, None]]"
0                                    date,2021-03-01  



df1 = df1.drop([0])
df1 = df1.T
df1 = df1.replace('data', '')
df1 = df1.replace('[', '')
df1 = df1.replace(']', '')
df1 = df1.replace([',', ''])
df1 = df1.replace(['.', ','])
```

What I get back is almost exactly the same thing I read in, still in only one :

```
Index: [data,"[[1614556800000, 1149], [1614643200000, 1512.1], [1614729600000, 2133.3], [1614816000000, 485.2], ....
```

I tried to seperate it by delimiter but that didn't seem to work as well. After that I also wanna get rid of the first number in the square brackets, but that I will try myself first.

Hope my problem is clear and anybody has a quick tip for me.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please include some sample data. You can reference [how to make a good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/9177877)

Comment: Yeah, please add the data you are getting just after reading the file. One improvement you can do is, df1 = df1.drop([0]).T.replace(['data', '[', ']', ','], '').replace('.', ',')

Comment: I tried to edit it in, I hope that helps. It's my first post maybe I'm not used to the controls here :D